# Merging Changes to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL Server database that sits client site. Users communicate with it through a C# application. I created a backup of the database so I can make changes to tables and stored procedures on my dev computer. How can I now merge my changes back into the database without affecting any data that may have been added to the server since my backup was made?
For what it's worth, I'm using Management Studio to work the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if may cause the conflicts if both of you have made the different changes to the same database, if yours are the priority, you can simply restore your backup files from their end

Answer (score 1):

If you really want those changes to be deployed on the production side then you could have saved the scripts which you have run in local db. Then take those scripts and run it on production db. In this way you can preserve the present data and other changes will get reflect on production side as per your scripts